# Why HashMap<String,String> is Unreachable code. HashMap in Java 8

Tags: hashmap, unreachable-code

I'm declaring a HashMap in Java 8, this:

```
HashMap<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
OR
HashMap<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The compiler show this error: unreachable code. When I put `HashMap<String, Object> nameMap = new HashMap<>()` this error disapears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible only.
1) Check ur compiler . Should be using correct version 1.8 even if u added jdk 1.8. I think for u this is set as 1.5 coz diamond operator (<>) was introduced in 1.7 I think.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reviewed my code, and I was putting the sentence after of a return. Sorry.